# Excel vba: Axis minimum scale sometimes doesn't get updated on chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a gui that provides min and max values for a selected axis, like the following for the x-axis:

```
'X-axis
If ListBox8.ListIndex = 0 Then
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = TI_Chart_Tool.MultiPage1.Pages(2).TextBox2.Text
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = TI_Chart_Tool.MultiPage1.Pages(2).TextBox3.Text

End If
```

At the time this occurs, the x-axis of the chart, should change accordingly, right? Initial passes, for both x and y axis, seem to work fine, while testing, i seemed to get into a state such that the chart values would only be updated, when i clicked on the chart area.

(Let me add, this state seems to occur after i change the y-axis to a logarithmic scale.)

Does anyone know how to always have the axis values be updated automatically, from within the code without having to click on the chart?

Thanks for any help!

Russ

Comment: You could try setting screenupdating off and then back on again: that sometimes triggers a refresh.